# Parsing POST request if value contains '&' character

Tags: c, cgi, query-string

How can I get 'key=value' pairs from GET/POST request when value contains '&', which is reserved as a separator? I mean if the request variables look like 'key1=val&ue1' and 'key2=valu&e2'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is not allowed to contain an <kbd>&</kbd> symbol. It may contain a logical `&` but the `&` must be %-encoded (<kbd>%</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>6</kbd>).

So split the string at each <kbd>&</kbd>, and then split the key and value in each segment at the first <kbd>=</kbd>, *before* %-decoding. (I've frequently seen the mistake of %-decoding the whole string prior to splitting it into pieces. That doesn't work, and this question demonstrates why not.)

Comment: Thanx, rici. I'll try as you recommend!

Comment: Now everything works just fine! The mistake really was %-decoding the whole string prior to splitting it into pieces!